# Symfony - get an entity object in a field constraint class

Tags: php, symfony, validation, constraints, symfony-2.8

I created my custom constraint validator:

```
class CustomConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message = '';
}

class CustomConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
         exit($this->context->getObject()); // returns null
    }
}
```

In [docs](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Validator/Context/ExecutionContextInterface.html) it is stated that:

> Returns the currently validated object.

, but for me it returns `NULL` instead.

P.S. I do not want to assign this constraint to Entity, only to certain forms or fields.

My form property which is validated:

```
->add('rejectReasons', null, array(
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true,
        'constraints' => array(
            new CustomConstraint(array(
                'message' => 'Application can not be refused.'
            )),
        )
    ));
```

Property in entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="RejectReason")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="relationship_application_reject_reasons",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="application_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="reject_reason_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $rejectReasons;
```

**UPDATE**

I tried putting constraint on other string property, I still get `NULL`.

Comment: Describe a specific use-case example to better understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create a constraint that check the entity if it is valid to execute some action. It should not be applied all the time to the entity, only to a certain forms. I can pass entity as an option (like a message is passed), but it is bad practice since symfony should be handling this functionnality using getObject()

Answer (score 6):

Look at [ExecutionContextInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Validator/Context/ExecutionContextInterface.html#method_getObject) it says that:

> getObject() Returns the currently validated object.
>
> If the validator is currently validating a **class constraint**, the
>   object of that class is returned. If it is a validating a **property or
>   getter constraint**, the object that the property/getter belongs to is
>   returned.
>
> **In other cases, null is returned.**

So as you can see, you have to assign to a class or a property or getter. Otherwise you will get `null`.

Comment: It is validating a property of entity which is ArrayCollection. See the update.

Comment: @IgnasDamunskis in your case, i suggest you to create a `rejectReasons` form type, and add data_class your entity, with cascade validation.

Answer (score 2):

For those making form validation using dependencies itself this can help.
I assume that the Symfony version is 3.4 or 4.1 and you have `symfony/form` on your project.

## Build your CustomConstraintValidator

The best way to deal with Symfony Form Validators with some kind of dependency are using CustomValidators

Above is a example that I use to work with them.

Supposed that we have an Entity like

```
// src/Entity/myEntity.php
namespace App\Entity;
...

class myEntity
{
    private $id;
    private $name; // string, required
    private $canDrive; // bool, not required (default=false)
    private $driveLicense; // string, not required (default = null)

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->canDrive = false;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

We don't need to populate `$driveLicense` (cause the attribute its not mandatory), but if `$canDrive`change from `false` to `true`, now `$driveLicense` **must** have a value.

**`$driveLicense` is `$canDrive` dependent.**

To build a form for that and validate `$driveLicense` correctly on the FormType (the best practice) we need to build a CustomConstraintValidator.

### Building CanDriveValidator

```
// src/Validator/Constraints/CanDrive.php
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class CanDrive extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'invalid_candrive_args'; // I like translators :D
}
```

Translator file - optional

```
//src/translators/validators.en.yaml // 
invalid_candrive_args: When "{{ candrivelabel }} " field is checked you must fill "{{ drivelicenselabel }}"
```

The validator

```
// src/Validator/Constraints/CanDriveValidator.php
namespace App\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class CanDriveValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    /**
     * Checks if the passed value is valid.
     *
     * @param mixed $value The value that should be validated
     * @param Constraint $constraint The constraint for the validation
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $canDriveField = $this->context->getObject(); // the Field using this validator
        $form = $canDriveField->getParent(); // the formType where the Field reside
        $myEntity = $form->getData(); // The Entity mapped by formType                
            
        if ($myEntity->getCanDrive() == true && $myEntity->getDriveLicense() == null) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ candrivelabel }}', 'Can Drive')
                ->setParameter('{{ drivelicenselabel }}', 'Drive License')
                ->addViolation();
        }            
    } 
}
```

The form myEntityType

```
//src/Form/myEntityType.php
namespace App\Form;
use App\Entity\myEntity;
use App\Validator\Constraints\CanDrive;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class myEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name') 
            ->add('canDrive', CheckBoxType::class, [
                    'required' => false,
                    'constraints' => array(new canDrive()),                    
                    ]                    
                )
            ->add('driveLicense', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
        ;

    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => myEntity::class]);
    }        
}
```

Now, when use call `isValid()` method of myEntityType form and the *canDrive* field was checked and *driveLicense* is blank, a Violation will be fired on canDrive field. If *canDrive* is set to false (not checked, not submitted), nothing happens and form will be valid even when *driveLicense* is blank.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Write :

```
this->context->getRoot()->getData()
```

and u have the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are develep a **Class Constraint Validator** remember to add the getTargets method as example:

```
public function getTargets()
{
    return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
}
```

As described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator) in the doc

Comment: It is a property constraint validator not a class.

Comment: hi @IgnasDamunskis if you need the whole object in order to validate the single field you need to use a class validator constraint

Comment: Doesn't that mean that class will be validated with each entity update? I need validation only in few cases

Comment: hi @IgnasDamunskis should indicate only the scope of application, make a try and see what happen :)